# Pebble iOS app crash when doing ajax via JavaScript framework

Tags: xmlhttprequest, pebble-watch

When loading some ajax via the PebbleKit JavaScript framework the app crashes, I can see via console.log() that the XMLHttpRequest.open() is called ok, but it doesn't get pass XMLHttpRequest.send().

I have had previous similar code working fine, but I have been unable to debug this issue.

It does not fire the onload event, nor timeout (at not that I can tell via console.log().

All I see in the pebble console is:

> [ERROR   ] Lost connection to Pebble

Looking at the composed url it does not appear to be malformed, and it loads ok in a desktop browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see via the iOS console (in xcode organiser), the error:

> PebbleApp[211] : *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL
>   URLByAppendingPathComponent:]: component, components, or pathExtension
>   cannot be nil.'

Digging deeper in I can see that one of the querystring elements simply had a space at the end. Removing the space solved the problem, so I can assume that it was due to it not being properly URLEncoded.

I would of thought that this would typically be handled fine by JavaScript running in mobile webkit, but I'm guessing as it's embedded into an app, it is stricter and threw a exception.

Notably this is in beta 2 of the 2.0 sdk, so it may already be easier to diagnose in later versions.

Comment: Alex, thanks for sharing your problem. We are aware of this crash condition and it will be fixed soon! (thomas@pebble)

Comment: I can see in the 2.0 beta 4 iOS change logs that "PebbleKit JS: Fixed a bug where a space in an URL opened with XmlHTTPRequest could crash the iOS app". Great.

Comment: Yep, fixed in beta 4 nice.